# What is the use of three separate routing table entries for loopback?

Tags: networking, loopback

The loopback address is `127.0.0.1/8` right? Then wouldn't the first entry (in red box) itself take care of all the loopbacks? What is the need for the next two entries (in blue box)? [image]

Comment: Note that you get 3 entries (well 4 with the multicast 224.0.0.0 routes for each network) for almost any network, and 127.0.0.0/8 is a network just like 192.168.1.0/24. one is the address on-link, one is the network ID, for any host in that network, and the broadcast for All IPs in that network.

Answer (score 3):

The first blue entry is a "host entry", this is automatically created for each network interface (including the loopback interface). Host entries enable special rules for specific hosts.

The second blue entry is the broadcast address for the entire network, this one is used to talk to all clients on the network without knowing the specific IP address (e.g. for network discovery). This is also automatically created for each network interface (including the loopback interface).

A multicast entry (`244.0.0.0/4`) and a broadcast entry (`255.255.255.255/32`) is also automatically created for each interface (five in total including the three you mentioned in your question).

PS. On a side note: it's not just `127.0.0.1` you can use for loopback, any address in the `127.0.0.0/8` space is valid (e.g. try `127.255.255.254`).